# How to Lock all Xcode files or make them un edit able?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

Hello I need to send my Xcode project to a client and i want to lock all the files, so he will not be able to made any changes or will not be able to edit the source code files.Is there any permanent solution for that?

Comment: Once he has a file copied onto his system he can do anything he wants to it.  The most you can do is "sign" them somehow so that any changes are detectable.

Comment: It may help if you explain your intention here, as opposed to your solution (which is "lock the files"). Also, what have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can put this xcode project into git repositorie , with https://bitbucket.org/ you can have unlimited repositories for free.

If your client use the command:git clone the url repositorie he/they can change whatever they want but not change the main project.

Best practice is git or other version control manager.

Comment: Of course, the OP could simply send this guy a zip file containing his files and achieve the same thing.